# sencha extjs6.0 Ext.window.window (diagnostic window) not able to search text (logs) which are not in the current frame using ctrl+f

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, diagnostics, extjs6-classic

The problem is whenever I search for any text/logs inside the diagnostic window using ctrl+f in the browser the text which is visible in the current frame is searchable but the same text which is not in the current frame i.e which exist in the diagnostic window but is not visible because of scroll is not searchable.
So, before extjs6.0 I was using extjs4.0 in which the this functionality was working completely fine.
Here is a screenshot link for the ext4.0 version in which search was working fine :
[image]

Here is another screenshot link for the ext6.0 version in which search is not working :[image]

Below is the code which is I am using for the diagnostic window.

```
/* This class defines the window where the Diagnostic Data wil be displayed 
in a grid.  */
Ext.define('Dragon.view.DiagnosticsWindow', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
alias: 'widget.osDiagnosticWindow',
closable: true,
maximizable: true,
constrain: true,
modal: true,
width: 950,
minWidth: 550,
height: 650,
title: Localize.processLocalStr('Diagnostics'), //'Diagnostics'.lclize(),
layout: 'fit',
bodyStyle: 'padding: 5px;',
config: {
/**
* @cfg {Object} diagnosticData 
* Custom config to get and set backend diagnostic data
*/
diagnosticData: {},
/**
* @cfg {String} userSessionId 
* Custom config to get and set user Session data
*/
userSessionId: '',
/**
* @cfg {String} transactionId 
* Custom config to get and set transaction Id
*/
transactionId: '',
/**
* @cfg {String} actionId 
* Custom config to get and set backend block data
*/
actionId: ''
},
items: []
});
```